# Access field from trait in companion object

Tags: scala

I have something like the following code (I simplified it):

```
trait A {
  val CONST_VALUE = 10
}

class B(someValue: Int, values: Array[Int]) extends A {   
  //some methods
}

object B {
  def apply(someValue: Int) = B(someValue, Array.ofDim[Array[Byte]](someValue).map(block => Array.fill[Byte](A.CONST_VALUE)(0)))
}
```

Basically, I declared a constant `CONST_VALUE` in the trait `A`. I am trying to use it in the companion object `B` to instantiate the class `B`. However, I can't access `A.CONST_VALUE` from the companion object `B`.(I'm getting a compilation error).

So how could I do this?

Comment: Sidenote - In order to make a variable constant, you need to add the `final` keyword: `final val CONST_VALUE = 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `val CONST_VALUE = 10` inside the companion object `A` instead of trait `A`. Also corrected the `apply` method definition in object `B`

```
trait A {

}

object A {
  final val CONST_VALUE = 10
}

class B(someValue: Int, values: Array[Int]) extends A {   
  //some methods
}

object B {
  def apply(someValue: Int) = new B(someValue, Array.ofDim[Int](someValue).flatMap(block => Array.fill[Int](A.CONST_VALUE)(0)))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this.

First of all, `object B` is the companion object to `class B`, not to `trait A`. Companions need to have the same name and be defined in the same compilation unit.

Secondly, `CONST_VALUE` is an instance field of `trait A`. It is a member of an *instance* of `A`, not a member of `A`.

Thirdly, when you say `A.CONST_VALUE` you are basically calling the method `CONST_VALUE` on `A`. But you can only call methods on objects/values. `A` is not an object, it is a *type*, types and values live in different worlds, you cannot mix the two.

And fourth, your `CONSTANT_VALUE` is misleadingly named: only `final val`s are constant value definitions, so your `CONSTANT_VALUE` is not actually a constant value.

Fifth, your `apply` method calls itself (`B()` is syntactic sugar for `B.apply()`), and thus needs a return type annotation.

Sixth, your `apply` method calls itself with *two* arguments, but it is defined with only *one* parameter.

Seventh, you create an `Array[Array[Byte]]`, but it is not clear to me why you want to do that and what you need it for.

That's a whole *truckload* of problems (especially considering that there are only a handful of lines of code to begin with), which you need to fix one-by-one. Here's one possible **partial** solution, but it is not clear to me what it is *exactly* that you are trying to achieve.

```
trait A

object A {
  final val CONST_VALUE = 10
}

class B(someValue: Int, values: Array[Int]) extends A {   
  //some methods
}

object B {
  def apply(someValue: Int): B = new B(
    someValue, 
    Array.ofDim[Array[Byte]](someValue).map(block => Array.fill[Byte](A.CONST_VALUE)(0)))
}
```